# Determinant of $3\times 3$ matrix $4I_3-2A$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, determinant

Let $A$ be a $3\times 3$ matrix such that $\det A=9$ and $2A-A^2=3I_3$ where $I_3$ is a unit matrix. Compute $\det (4I_3-2A)$.

From the assumption, we have

$4I_3-2A=I_3^2-A^2=(I_3-A)(I_3+A)$.

But I don't know how to go on. Could you please give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$3I = 2A-A^2 = A(2I-A)$, hence $2I-A = 3A^{-1}$, i.e., $4I-2A = 6A^{-1}$.
$$
\Longrightarrow\quad \det(4I-2A) = \det(6A^{-1}) = 6^3\cdot\frac 1 {\det A} = \frac{36\cdot 6}{9} = 24.
$$

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$\det(2A-A^2)=\det(A(2I-A))=\det(A)\det(2I-A)=\det(3I_3)=27$$
So
$$\det(2I-A)=27/9=3$$
Therefore
$$\det(4I-2A)=\det(2(2I-A))=2^3\det(2I-A)=2^3\times 3=24$$